# Changing the country in Google Play Store

Tags: geolocation, google-play-store

I've moved from Canada to Australia.  I go to try and buy a Nexus 4, but it's insisting on showing me prices in the play store (google.com/nexus) for Canadian dollars.  I can only find one country setting in my Google account, and that was in the Calender.  Sadly, that didn't fix it.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Try clearing your cookies for the Google Play store domain?

Comment: Have done that, obliterated cache and all cookies. I suppose it's technically the Nexus store, not the play store, but still - nothing I do seems to let me choose Australia...

Comment: Don't have the rep to post an answer, but got this to work.  Update address to new country in accounts, add new country card, remove old country cards (even if you can still use them), then had to wait for 24 hours before play realised and updated.  Was trying to get a banking app not available in my origin country installed, finally appeared.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is obsolete. The Google Nexus store no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Google payments help page [Change your home, business, or billing address and country](https://support.google.com/payments/answer/6220310?hl=en):

> Each [payments profile](https://support.google.com/payments/answer/7124239?hl=en&ref_topic=6209953) can be associated only with one country due to tax regulations on the payment methods you pay with. You **can't** change the country for an existing payments profile and need to create a new profile to add another country. Creating a new payments profile in another country does not affect your existing services and subscriptions. They will continue to be paid with the associated payments profile.
>
> If you are moving or traveling to a new country and want to sign up for new services or pay for products in that country, you will have to create a new payments profile.
>
> When you have multiple payments profiles set up with different countries, you have the option to choose the account for payment.

### Create a payments profile with a new country

1. Sign in to [Settings](http://payments.google.com/#settings).
2. Under **Payments profile**, click the pencil icon next to **Country**.
3. Click the link to **Create new profile** from the message that appears.
4. Click **Continue** from the next message that appears.
5. From the drop-down list, choose the country to associate with the payments profile you're creating.
6. Enter the address information and click **Submit**.

Answer (score 0):

Set up an additional user account and link it to an Australian credit card.  The problem might be the fact that your payment information is still tied to a CAN$ card.

Comment: Sadly no, it's actually tied to a NZ credit card (I travel a lot) so that's not it either :/